# New Preview BigQuery UI Zoom Shortcut

Tags: google-bigquery

I keep accidentally hitting some key combination that zooms out in the editor of the new Bigquery UI and cannot figure out how to reset it to the actual zoom level without refreshing the entire page. The shell of the editor does not zoom and is the only part of the UI that responds to the normal Chrome zoom shortcuts, however the editor window remains zoomed at the altered level and does not change, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sIxO.png)

Answer (score 0):

On my Macbook, the zoom-in/out could be triggered with Command + 2 finger touchpad up/down.

I don't have a Windows to try, but if you need Windows key, I guess the counterpart is Ctrl + Mouse scroll up/down.